# Is this a basis of $\mathbb{R^4}:$ $\;(1,1,-1,2),\; (1,0,1,-1),\; (2,-1,1,-1)\;\;?$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Do the vectors below form a basis of $\mathbb R^4\;?$ $$(1,1,-1,2),\; (1,0,1,-1),\; (2,-1,1,-1)$$

I tried to represent them as a linear combination equaling zero, and the equations arose from it.

$a+b+2c =0$,

$ a-c = 0$

$-a+b+c =0$

$2a-b-c =0$

So do I want to find the reduced row echelon of the coefficient matrix? How do I do this with 4 equations and 3 unknowns?

Comment: Do you mean "do the vectors form a basis for a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$"?

Comment: No, I don't. This is right out of the textbook.

Comment: Form the vectors as the columns of a matrix and row reduce to get a basis of the subspace your vectors span.

Comment: You can't get a basis from this, can you?

Comment: The three vectors span some subspace and, yes, that subspace has a basis.  The only question is whether the three vectors you have are linearly independent.  If the reduced form shows that there are three vectors in the basis then your original vectors are linearly independent and themselves form a basis of that subspace.

Comment: Well, the other guy says that there is no basis.

Comment: The other guy says that the three vectors are not a basis for all of $\mathbb{R}^4$.  I agree with that.  The three vectors could be a basis for a subspace that has dimension smaller than 4.

Comment: I don't need a subspace, which is why I didn't say 'subspace'. But thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, to have a basis of $\mathbb R^4$ you need $4$ linearly independent vectors. You have only three such vectors.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it didn't make any sense; I figured it wasn't a basis, just didn't know if that is a good enough answer haha!

Comment: You're welcome, Math.

Comment: Wait, I've never seen anyone or any part of the book write it like that..... It's always done the way I did it...

Comment: Since $a, b, c$ are vectors; they are not scalars. So each has four components. $2a$ means $2 \times $ every component of vector a, for example. Perhaps you've seen $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)^T?$. The index represents the row in which the component sits.

Comment: Your equations only hold component wise. If you want to find a linear combination of $4$ vectors, then you need such combination  to be the sum of scalar multiples of entire vectors.

Comment: Since I am confusing you, I will delete the latter part of my answer.

Comment: I just checked the answer in the back of the book, and it wrote it just like I did.